# My heart has been made up - what does it mean?

Tags: idioms, phrasal-verbs

If a person says "my heart has been made up and I choose you" when talking about someone he likes - what exactly does the part "my heart has been made up" mean? What has happened to his heart and feelings? What kind of emotions is it related to and in which order?

Comment: Who said this? Is this real speech that someone said to you?

Comment: This is a phrase an American native speaker used in his writing. I know the phrase I made up my mind. But never heard about making up someone's heart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is word-play, or perhaps a mixing of expressions.

We say "My mind is made up" to mean "I have made a decision".

But love and relationships are matters of the the "heart" not the "mind".

So this person has mixed the two ideas, and invented "my heart is made up".  Presumably It means "I have made a decision in a matter of love"